# Timezone issue while converting date generated from fullcalendar in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, timezone, fullcalendar, strtotime

While converting date that generated form **jQuery fullcalendar**, the timezone making some problem in **Windows**.

Here is the values that i am posting, to recognize error i have made `start` variable as string in `(IST)`, and the end is the value that getting as response from **jQuery fullcalendar** there the timezone is in `(India Standard Time)` as you see. Please refer the pic of console

[image]

And after converting the start and end variables using `strtotime()` in php, what i got is

[image]

Here is the code stuff that i used for converting:

```
        $dat = array(
                    'eve_start' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['start'])),
                    'eve_end' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['end'])),
                    'eve_allDay' => 0
                );
```

You can notice that the `eve_end` is not getting correctly because of `(India Standard Time)`

Comment: Basically the problem here is, that you are posting a invalid date formats, because datetimes cannot have double timezone specifications. I think [fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io) works with ISO8601 datetime formats, so it is probably your fault for sending wrong formats. Why don't you fix the POST, to send correct datetimes? Show us the JS code...

Comment: first image of console shows the date formats both in windows and linux...
No wrong with post element format, the problem here is the timezone is getting in expandable form in windows and that makes error while formating date in php

Comment: So you are saying that your script post's different formats in different systems?

Comment: yeah, that's it
in windows it is (India Standard Time) but in linux it is (IST)

Comment: Can you show us the ajax request part of your javasript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$start = substr($_POST['start'], 0, strpos($_POST['start'], '('));
$end = substr($_POST['end'], 0, strpos($_POST['end'], '('));

$start_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($start));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($end));
$dat = array(
                'eve_start' => $start_date,
                'eve_end' => $end_date,
                'eve_allDay' => 0
            );
```